# Почему "русский" (национальность) прилагательное?

Tags: этимология, грамматика

Ответьте, если сможете, на вопрос: почему этническая принадлежность русских обозначается только именем прилагательным "русский", почему не существительным, к примеру, как американец, немец, украинец и т.д. (прошу не путать с россиянином)?

Answer (score 1):

**Русский** —  частично субстантивированное прилагательное (прилагательное, перешедшее в существительное), возникло из сочетания "русские люди".

Материал на эту тему (об истории названия русского этноса) можно посмотреть в  **Википедии.**

"Этноним рѹсь (ед.ч. м.р. рѹсинъ, ж.р. рѹска) употреблялся как самоназвание до XVIII века. С XVII—XVIII веков он постепенно заменился на искусственные россияне, а позднее с XVIII—XIX веков — на великоруссы. В XVIII—XIX веках **из разговорного языка** в литературный проник и закрепился уже известный этноним русские".